# How to use iron-dropdown in Polymer 1.0?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

This maybe the simplest but for me I have no idea; [their website](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-dropdown) is also not clear.

I have updated my bower.json file to use version 1.0.3 of the Iron Elements, imported the iron-dropdown elements but nothing shows when I have this:

```
  <iron-dropdown>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </iron-dropdown>
```

Am I missing something?

**Edit:**

This also shows nothing:

```
<iron-dropdown horizontal-align="right" vertical-align="top">
  <div class="dropdown-content">Hello!</div>
</iron-dropdown>
```

If it helps, I'm using Polymer Starter Kit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess I'll answer this myself as this is with less code. Apparently you need an id on the `<iron-dropdown>` itself then calling the function `show` shows the hidden content:

```
<button on-click="show">Click me</button>
<iron-dropdown id="showMenu" horizontal-align="right" vertical-align="top">
  <div class="dropdown-content">Hello!</div>
</iron-dropdown>

<script>
 show: function() {
 this.$.showMenu.toggle();
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing the `dropdown-content` div ?

Check the demo tab and right click on the Basic dropdown to see it's structure.. Also from the doc page :

```
<iron-dropdown horizontal-align="right" vertical-align="top">
  <div class="dropdown-content">Hello!</div>
</iron-dropdown>
```

This is the code from their demo Basic Button.

```
<button class="dropdown-trigger">Basic</button>
<div class="style-scope iron-dropdown" id="contentWrapper">
  <ul class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">alpha</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">beta</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">gamma</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">delta</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">epsilon</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I was looking at it but...not sure that's the correct way. So where is `<iron-dropdown></iron-dropdown>` and how to correctly use it? Seems like I need to write a function?

Comment: I don't code with it but based on what I saw you make a trigger ( in this case the button with class `"dropdown-trigger"`) and then you make the "iron-dropdown" div, inside you place your list ( ul with class `"dropdown-content`" ) I don't think you need a function for that since it pretty much looks like bootstrap.

Pay attention that you used `<iron-dropdown>` and the example uses a `<div class="iron-dropdown">`

Comment: Ignore the pay attention part.

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown element initial display status is hidden.

So you need to provide a way to open it, i.e. with a related button.

I've created a sample

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-dropdown/iron-dropdown.html">
    <title>Dropdown Polymer minimal sample</title>
</head>
<body>
<paper-button>flat button</paper-button>
<iron-dropdown horizontal-align="right" vertical-align="top">
    <div class="dropdown-content">This is the content inside the dropdown!</div>
</iron-dropdown>

<script>
    var button=  document.querySelector('paper-button');
    button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var dropdown = document.querySelector('iron-dropdown');
        dropdown.open();
    });
    window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function(e) {
        var dropdown = document.querySelector('iron-dropdown');
        dropdown.close();
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Hi. Could you plunkr this as it does not work for me?

Comment: Few issues with that. 1: contents only hide in chrome, not in firefox. When a content is selected, nothing changes (in chrome). I dont think their element is ready for production.